# Unfortunately Google+ has stopped in android

Tags: java, android, google-plus

when I try to crop image using the crop intent I am getting a pop up "Unfortunately Google+ has stopped".

my code is..

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        if (bitmap == null)
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        else {
            cropIntent.setType("image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("data", bitmap);
        }
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_REQUEST);
```

**Note:This problem is occurring after updating Google+.When I uninstall update of google plus no problem occures..So is there any bug with new Google+ ? or should I change something in code?**

Comment: The `com.android.camera.action.CROP` intent is not public and should not be considered neither available or reliable. I can tell from practice that there are a lot a devices that do not support the intent.

Comment: what is the solution ?????????????????????